# How to implement a butterworth filter over a 2D np.array of a medical image in python

Tags: python, smoothing, imaging, medical, butterworth

I want to smooth a medical image using a butterworth filter, the data is very noisy and I want to reduce this. I am using Python v3.7. The image data is stored in a 2D np.array, which I transformed to the frequency domain using scipy. I don't know what step is next to be able to apply a butterworth filter

```
#%% butterworth filter
import scipy.fftpack
import scipy.signal
normal_scan=scan_spect # I have already loaded and preprocessed the data 
freq_scan=scipy.fftpack.fft2(normal_scan)

N=10 #order/power of the filter

Wn=0.6 #critical frequency

B, A=scipy.signal.butter(10,0.6, output='ba' )

smoothed_data=scipy.signal.filtfilt(B, A, freq_scan)
```

What format does my data have to be in to be able to apply the butterworth filter? And which parameters do I use.

Answer (score 4):

This is my approach I don't know if it clears enough noise for you .
I am also suggesting to make the order 4

```
def butterLow(cutoff, critical, order):
    normal_cutoff = float(cutoff) / critical
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass')
    return b, a

def butterFilter(data, cutoff_freq, nyq_freq, order):
    b, a = butterLow(cutoff_freq, nyq_freq, order)
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

x=np.array(freq_scan)
cutoff_frequency = some value
sample_rate = maximum value in your array *2 +1

y = butterFilter(x, cutoff_frequency, sample_rate/2)
```

This will give you the low pass butterworth if you want the high pass output:

```
high=np.array(x)-np.array(y)
```